# Error when jsonifying model instances

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have the following code:

```
def getRestaurants():    
    restaurant_list = session.query(RESTAURANT).all()
    return jsonify(restaurant_list)


class RESTAURANT(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'RESTAURANT'

    RESTAURANTID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    RESTAURANTNAME = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    RESTAURANTDESCRIPTION = Column(String(1024))

    def serialize(self):
        return {        
            'RESTAURANTID': self.RESTAURANTID, 
            'RESTAURANTNAME': self.RESTAURANTNAME,
            'RESTAURANTDESCRIPTION': self.RESTAURANTDESCRIPTION        
        }

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.str

    def __str__(self):        
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')
```

When I call `getRestaurants` I get the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What line is the syntax error on? Also, what is `self.str`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jsonify` takes any number of `(key, value)` pairs, as well as `key=value` keywords.  You are passing a list of model instances instead, which is not a sequence of pairs.  Instead, use something such as `jsonify(data=restaurant_list)`.

After that, adding the method `serialize` does not make the model json seralializable.  You need to call serialize yourself and pass that result to `jsonify`.

```
def getRestaurants():
    return jsonify(data=[r.serialize() for r in session.query(RESTAURANT)])
```